# Pagination between amp pages from joomla

Tags: joomla, amp-html

I'm new in Stack Overflow.

I have a question: 
I created a website in Joomla: vers. 3.6.2 and work fine.

Today I have installed a wbAMP plugin (free edition). It work well.

Now, I have a question:

In a demo site, I have seven blog articles.

When I view the seventh (amp) article, and I click to go to the sixth (previous), the plugin come back to the sixth article of the website and not 
to the sixth article amp.

Am I wrong or some other has the same thing?

Comment: It may be best to contact the wbAMP plugin developer for an answer as this is a commercial extension and presumably comes with support.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for your response.
I will buy the commercial version.
Thanks again.
Regards
Floyd